# PHP Mailer "Thank You" Message After Form Is Sent

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a PHP form ready, with sucesss message after the form is being sent. Thing is that the message shows after the page is redirected to the phpmailer.php

How can I make the message show after the user clicks submit? My final goal is to make the form disappear and show the thank you message instead.

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$youremail = 'email-here@gmail.com';
$fromsubject = 'domain-here.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['message']; 
    $to = $youremail; 
    $mailsubject = 'Masage recived from'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
    $body = $fromsubject.'

    The person that contacted you is  '.$name.'
     E-mail: '.$mail.'

     Message: 
     '.$message.'

    |---------END MESSAGE----------|'; 
echo "Thank you fo your feedback."; 
                                mail($to, $subject, $body);
 } else { 
echo "You must write a message"; 
}
?>
```

Here's the PHP code:

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show the message in a javascript alert from your mailer code. Means replace `echo "Thank you fo your feedback."; `  with a javascript alert.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax in your mail page, make the process page is seperate from the write page. After user clicks 'Send', post the data to the process page and respond with a text message or json data, and show the message on the write page

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your-url-to-send-mail-page',
    type: 'POST',
    data: maildata,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('An error occurs!');
    }
});
```

------UPDATE------

write.php :

```
<form id="mailForm">
    <input type="text" name="Submit" value="" />
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" />
    <textarea name="content" rows="30" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button id="sendBtn">Send</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maildata = new FormData($("#mailForm")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'send.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: maildata,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('An error occurs!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

so it should alert "Thank you fo your feedback." after click on the send button.

Comment: I dont understand there to implement this :( Please help me

Comment: make 2 pages and one for write and another for send, use jQuery to bind this ajax to your "send" button, and make send page echo thank you message after the mail is sent, so the previous page receives the message and show it out.
Sorry for poor english